# Impossible referrers

Tags: statistics, referrer

I'm tracking webpage referrers. Sometimes I see russian (or other languages) blogs as referrer, which cover other subjects.

Googling "site:http://myrussianblog.ru mywebsite" returns nothing.

I don't use advertising systems.

What these referrer mean?

I know that referrer field can be changed.. but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that referrer field can be changed.. but why?

This is known as [referrer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam) - unfortunately, spammers caught on to the fact that [some webmasters](https://www.google.com/?q=%22Usage%20Statistics%22%20%22Summary%20Period%22%20inurl%3awebstats&oq=%22Usage%20Statistics%22%20%22Summary%20Period%22%20inurl%3awebstats) do not secure their automatically-generated stat reports and, as most report generators do not add nofollow to referrer links, it is possible to get a link from a number of domains simply by providing a falsified referrer.